# Total newbie! Very lost on how to send json data through flask to display on an HTML webpage?

Tags: html, mysql, json, flask, backend

I'm very new to backend web dev as well as frontend web dev. Right now, I've got a python script that uses flask to spin up a webserver. I have a method in this script that takes the name of a story as input, and returns the text as part of a larger JSON set (see code snippet). Separately, I have an HTML page through which I am trying to display this returned JSON data from the webserver. What I'm trying to figure out is... how do I make the HTML page and JSON server talk to one another? Right now I'm using Postman to access the returned JSON data. I know that the render_template function should be called in the return function with the variable 'data' as the parameter... but I'm not sure what to do after that? Any help is very much appreciated.

I've looked at a LOT of stack overflow posts but the responses are not quite exactly what I'm looking for... either that, or the answers are too advanced for me to understand what is being described.

```
@app.route('/story/<title>', methods=["GET"])
def display_story(title):

    db = MySQLdb.connect("mysql-server", "root", "secret", "mydb")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE title = %s", (title,))
    rows = cursor.fetchone()
    if (rows != None):
        data = {"title": rows[0], "text": rows[1], "current_user": rows[2], "state": rows[3]}
        db.close()
        resp = Response(json.dumps(data), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        return resp

    data = { "Error": "There is no story with that title." }
    resp = Response(json.dumps(data), status=404, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp
```

Comment: If you just want to build an HTML page, I'd find it easier just to pass your `resp` to `render_template()` as a `dict` rather than `json` and use [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) to access the items. E.g. `return render_template('index.html', resp=resp)`.

Comment: Also note your SQL is extremely exposed to an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @PGHE which is the right way I also have been doing it that way

Comment: Got it - I'll give your suggestions a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Ill give a quick solution to your problem right now. 
Firstly, your method of SQL Querying? its not that good. You need to use SQLAlchemy for example to make it better. 
Secondly, you dont need to pass a JSON with the query data for it to be accessible to your web page, there is a WAY simpler method, JINJA.

And I'll attach some exellent recourses below which will helo you learn more, in a week or less. Its the same one I used to start out in Flask. Absolutely basic and easy all your questions will get answered there. Thats the more detailed one, if you dont under my solution below, use that to learn.

So the solution:

1. Implement [SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/). Makes life way simple and makes querying easy. 
   How it works is maybe a few days read so I will leave a link with you, which you can start to read to understand better.
   Your query in SQLAlchemy will looklike this.

```
query = db.session.query(stories).filter(stories.title == xyz).all()
```

then the variable query can be called in render_template and passed to the HTML page. 
like so,

```
return render_template('webpage.html', title='XYZ', query=query)
```

I'm also assuming that your table looks something along the lines of this,

```
class stories(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stories'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
```

2. Learn [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/), its a templating engine which makes Python - HTML interactions simple. 
   In your HTML page, you can use they data got in query like this,

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
Title : {{query.title}}
Text : {{query.text}}
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And your HTML page will show the query data without the hassle of using JSON to send data and all which you are currently doing.

**RESOURCES for Learning :**

Since you are a newbie and this question shows your knowledge on this front is very limited. I will HIGHLY RECOMMEND this Youtube Series.

Watch the first 4-5 for basic knowledge on how Flask, Jinja and SQL Alchemy work. Link here : [Corey M Schafer's Guide to Flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH).

Everything is explained clearly and shown too.

At the end of this video series, atleast the first 4 videos, you'll be able to create simple database driven web pages using Flask like a basic blog site (Looking at your code, that's somewhat along the lines of what you are doing.)